# What are the tradeoffs in executing DMLs as in Test code so that tests can be run in parallel

Tags: apex, unit-test

We have some classes that do not have the `@isTest(isParallel=true)` notation, because we are upserting Users, Group Members, etc.

What are the tradeoffs in annoting the class as `@isTest(isParallel=true)`, and performing the upserts in `System.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId()){....}`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that change would impact parallelization. Could you flesh out the example?

Comment: RunAs won't help